# Regex for filename if known extension

Tags: c#, regex, notepad++

I have come up with a regex to find me all the image within a project.

```
(\/|\\)(.*)\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg)
```

What I am trying to do now, is find the extension (gif|jpg|etc...) and then capture the word preceeding that match (ie the filename).

I'm totally stuck on how to structure a lookbehind capture group(??)

What I am doing is looking through a large web project finding all the images that have been actually used in code, and then I'm going to clean up the image directory for ones that are no longer referenced.

Comment: The filename is in group 2. What language are you using?

Comment: c# and notepad++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Npp, you could search:

```
([^\/\\]+)(?=\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg))
```

or

```
([^\/\\]+)(?=\.(?:gif|png|jpe?g))
```

to match the filename.

According to comment, you can do the find/replace with:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*?([^\/\\]+\.(?:gif|png|jpe?g)).*?$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

This will remove everything in a line except the filename+extension.

Comment: This really helped. The next thing I was trying to do was Find/Replace in NPP and essentially blank out the line of all characters except for $1.$2 so I would just be left with the filename.ext on that line.